# Performing transformation with pyproj?

Tags: python, coordinate-system, pyproj

This seems like it should be straight forward, but I'm struggling to get the correct transformation from my state plane to lat long.

My code is as follows

```
# projection from spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/2992/
# oregon is espg ref 2992
projection = r'+proj=lcc +lat_1=43 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=41.75 +lon_0=-120.5 +x_0=399999.9999984 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +to_meter=0.3048 +no_defs'

osp2992 = Proj(projection)
```

Now when I try and check against the input/output they show in the upper right corner

```
# Input Coordinates: -119.88481361812, 43.453242550659 
# Output Coordinates: 1475673.108308, 621492.180223

>>>osp2992(-119.88481361812, 43.453242550659) 
(449785.16341222316, 189430.81653184193)
```

It's way off.

I'm not sure where I went wrong.

Edit: removed the to_meter conversion and still getting wrong output

```
projection = r'+proj=lcc +lat_1=43 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=41.75 +lon_0=-120.5 +x_0=399999.9999984 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +no_defs'

>>>osp2992(-119.88481361812, 43.453242550659) 
(550261.2548834425, 157725.95224630416)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test output coordinates are in feet, while pyproj is giving you the answer in meters, which is what it does by default

Define your projection this way instead :

```
osp2992 = Proj(projection, preserve_units=True)
osp2992(-119.88481361812, 43.453242550659)
(1475673.1083078186, 621492.18022257846)
```

Comment: As dumb as I feel having that, I'm still getting the wrong output.

Comment: yeah, I tried removing the +meter as well, but you're definitely getting the right answer, just in the wrong unit. According to http://pyproj.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/pyproj.Proj-class.html the default return value is supposed to be meters. You can supposedly add an optional keyword argument of preserve_units=True to make it use your projections unit of measure, but that didn't work for me. Anyway, converting to feet isn't that hard.

Comment: Ok so it's just a unit thing. I tried the epsg2993 projection and it works fine out of the gate for whatever reason. I'll just convert for the 2992.

Comment: I figured out how to use it properly. See edited answer